# Sending data from Arduino to textfile to compare, and then return a value/boolean

Tags: file, text, arduino, compare

I'm new to this so apologies of I've misunderstood anything.

I currently have an arduino uno and an RFID reader. What I want to do is use the RFID reader to take in the RFID number from the RFID tag, send it over the serial port to a text file, compare to see if the RFID number is in the text file and then return and turn on an LED light if it is, so if it is then a boolean true/false might do it?

I've read up on some tutorials and turning on the LED lights based on a particular value seems fine but getting the value through the process outlined is whats troubling me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

You need some sort of client application which can read the text file and communicate with the Arduino. You cannot "send" anything to a text file (just like you cannot "send" anything to an image or audio file, etc.). Many people use [Processing](http://processing.org/) to create simple clients and there are many [tutorials](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/connecting-arduino-to-processing) about how to do this. Obviously this means you need a computer on which to run the Processing client which is tethered to the Arduino by USB or else communicating with the Arduino through some wireless mode.

If you want a standalone solution, you could look into storing the text file data on the Arduino itself - in [Flash](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Memory) memory, if the data is small, or on an [SD card](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/SDCardNotes) if the data is large.

Walk before running.